# Sorting a LinkedList by value

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have a linkedlist structure and every nodes store the *int ID* number ,*string name* variable and *Node link* variable. I want to sort this list increasing order according to ID. Is the collection.sort suitable for this? How can I handle practically?

Comment: Is it your own implementation of LinkedList or you used one provided by jdk `java.util.LinkedList`?

Comment: Own implementation

Comment: Then `Collections.sort` wont help and you would need to write your own code for sorting list.

Comment: if it is your own implementation then you need to implement sorting algorithm in your LinkedList. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_sorts

Comment: @SMA You are wrong, because `Collections.sort` can be used with a custom comparator.

Comment: @JMax - Have a look at the signature of sort here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-

Answer (score 1):

You have two alternatives:

1. Let your Node class implements the `Comparable`  interface and implement the `compareTo(NodeType other)` like this: `return Integer.compare(this.id, other.id)`.
2. Use `Collections.sort` on your LinkedList with a custom Comparator:
   `Collections.sort(list, (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a.getId(),b.getId())`.